# Preserving variables in a function

Tags: javascript

I have a timer loop which I wish to perform one action ever three loops and then perform another action on the forth loop, and then repeat itself.  I thought the following would work, but found that `counter` is not defined the next time `MyLoop()` is executed.  It will be defined if I declare it in the global namespace, but then each loop will not have its own timer.  How can I preserve the `counter` value within `MyLoop()`?

```
function MyLoop(t) {
  console.log(counter);
  if (typeof counter === 'undefined') {
    var counter = 0;
  }
  setTimeout(function() {
    if (counter >= 3) {
      console.log('MAIN: Counter: ' + counter + ' Loop ' + t + ' seconds.')
      counter = 0;
    } else {
      console.log('SUB:  Counter: ' + counter + ' Loop ' + t + ' seconds.')
      counter++
    }
    MyLoop(t);
  }, t * 1000);
}

MyLoop(2);
MyLoop(4);
```

Comment: Ah, I think I got it.  Just pass `counter` back to itself?  For instance, `function MyLoop(t,counter) {...`, and then `MyLoop(t,counter);`.

Comment: That should work.

Comment: Or you can wrap *MyLoop* in an IIFE to keep a closure to *counter*.

Comment: @RobG  Originally, I did so, but then the script within it was initially executed the first time it was hit and not just after the first timer expired.  Probably can be done so wrapped within an IIFE, but just had to be differently than what I had done.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very small sample that demonstrates the issue:

```
function S(condition) { 
  var v; 
  if (condition) {v  = 42;} 
}
S(true);
S(false);
```

Do you expect `v` to be set to 42 on second call? Probably not, the same for your second call to `MyLoop`.

You are re-creating closure every iteration - instead re-use the same function you called first:

```
function MyLoop(t) {
  console.log(counter);
  if (typeof counter === 'undefined') {
    var counter = 0;
  }
  var onTick = function() {
    if (counter >= 3) {
      console.log('MAIN: Counter: ' + counter + ' Loop ' + t + ' seconds.')
      counter = 0;
    } else {
      console.log('SUB:  Counter: ' + counter + ' Loop ' + t + ' seconds.')
      counter++
    }
     setTimeout(onTick, t * 1000);
  };
  setTimeout(onTick, t * 1000);
}
```

Alternatively you can re-create function with correct counter:

```
function MyLoop(t, counter) {

 counter = counter || 0;

 setTimeout(function() {
    if (counter >= 3) {
      console.log('MAIN: Counter: ' + counter + ' Loop ' + t + ' seconds.')
      counter = 0;
    } else {
      console.log('SUB:  Counter: ' + counter + ' Loop ' + t + ' seconds.')
      counter++
    }
    MyLoop(t, counter); // creates new function with updated counter
  }, t * 1000);
}
```

Comment: Given your "very small sample", of course not!  Don't know why I thought differently with my script...  Also, thank you for the bonus regarding not re-creating closure.

Comment: I know that "not creating closure" was not the topic of my question, but what is different with your second example from my originally one only being modified by passing the counter back?  Thank you.  EDIT.  I first thought "creating closure" was a bad thing in which more memory is being used to repeatedly recreating functions or something, and probably this comment makes no sense and should be disregarded.

Comment: It is essentially the same except `counter` is passed on subsequent iterations. As you've noticed in your comment you can create correct function every iteration (on with expected `counter`) - `MyLoop(t, counter);` still creates new closure on every iteration, but it now contains expected value of counter. Note that since `counter` is parameter it does not need `var counter` anymore (Side note: your original defining variable inside `if` makes no difference - see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting)

Comment: Also, your first script creates an immediate loop and crashed my browser. I think it is because `onTick();` instantly calls itself. Guess I should go with the second!

Comment: Indeed it should *not* have called itself - should be the same as original - `setTimeout(onTick, t * 1000);`. Updated code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a recursive function that achieves what you need.

```
function theCountDown(tm, n) {
    window.setTimeout( myLoop(n) , tm * 1000);
}

function myLoop (t) {
var counter = t;

    if (counter > 1) {
        counter--;
      console.log('MAIN: Counter: ' + counter + ' Loop ' + t + ' seconds.');

      myLoop(counter);
    } else {
      console.log('SUB:  Counter: ' + counter + ' Loop ' + t + ' seconds.');
    }
}

myLoop(8);
```

### With setTimeout

```
function theCountDown(n) {
    window.setTimeout( myLoop(n) , 2000);
}

function myLoop (t) {
var counter = t;

    if (counter > 1) {
        counter--;
      console.log('MAIN: Counter: ' + counter + ' Loop ' + t + ' seconds.');
      myLoop(counter);
    } else {
      console.log('SUB:  Counter: ' + counter + ' Loop ' + t + ' seconds.');
    }
}

theCountDown(8, 4);
```